# Почему у указателя два адреса?

Tags: c++, указатели, память, стек

pd адрес переменной, а &pd адрес на другой блок памяти или тип данных? pd храниться в стеке, а &pd в куче?

```
double* pd = new double;
*pd = 10.3;
cout << "*pd = " << *pd<<endl;
cout << "pd = " << pd << endl;
cout << "&pd = " << &pd << endl;
```

результат

```
*pd = 10.3
pd = 00B0D7A0
&pd = 0093FDF8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&pd` - это адрес ячейки, где хранится сам указатель `pd`. Логично, что у него другой адрес.

pd хранится скорее всего в стеке (хотя если это переменная-член класса, то может быть и в куче).

То, куда указывает pd (`&pd`) в данном случае скорее всего хранится в куче (да, можно переопределить new и тогда можно разместить даже  в стеке).

"где хранится `&pd`" - а это выражение, ему не нужно явно хранится, пока его не сохранят.

Answer (score 3):

Какие "два разных адреса"?

```
cout << "*pd = " << *pd<<endl;
```

Это значение, находящееся по адресу, хранящемуся в переменной `pd`.

```
cout << "pd = " << pd << endl;
```

Это значение адреса, хранящееся в переменной `pd`.

```
cout << "&pd = " << &pd << endl;
```

Это адрес в памяти, где хранится переменная `pd`.

Это все - разные значения...